# Фильтрация List по повторяющемуся полю

Tags: java, list, java-stream

У меня есть коллекция объектов.
Мне нужно чтобы на выходе остались только коллекция объектов с уникальными значениями по одному полю.

я написал решение, но может есть какое то более изящное, без мапы.

вот коллекция объектов Load. Мне нужно чтобы в итоге осталась коллекция с уникальными значениями S. т.е. "1","2","3".
какое значение из дубликатов останется не принципиально.

```
    List<Load> file = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(new Load(1, "1"), new Load(2, "2"), new Load(3, "3"), new Load(4, "3"), new Load(4, "3"), new Load(6, "3")));

    public void filter() {
        Set<Load> fileSet = new HashSet<>(file);
        Map<String, Load> keySet = new HashMap<>();
        file.forEach(e -> keySet.put(e.getS(), e));
        System.out.println(keySet.values());
    }
}

class Load {
    int i;
    String s;
}
```

Comment: Переопределите equals/hascode в классе на нужное поле и сложите в коллекцию через stream и distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В представленном решении в мапу всегда будет записываться последний элемент в исходном списке, то есть результатом будет `[Load(1, "1"), Load(2, "2"), Load(6, "3")]`.

Также в методе `filter` не используется сет `fileSet`.

В общем случае, для отфильтровывания дубликатов так или иначе придётся пользоваться мапой, но это можно реализовать "неявным" образом при помощи коллектора [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), и здесь особое значение будет иметь определение функции слияния (merge function):

```java
public void filterByS() {
    Set<Load> filteredSet = new HashSet<>(
        file.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Load::getS,     // ключ для мапы
                v -> v,         // значение в мапе - экземпляр Load
                (v1, v2) -> v1  // функция слияния для совпадающих ключей
            )) // Map<String, Load>
            .values() // Collection<Load>
    );

    System.out.println(filteredSet);
}
```

Например:

- `(v1, v2) -> v1` -- выбор только первого элемента `Load(3, "3")`
- `(v1, v2) -> v2` -- выбор только последнего элемента `Load(6, "3")`
- `(v1, v2) -> Math.random() < 0.5 ? v1 : v2` -- случайный выбор элемента

Comment: а если переопределить у класса Load `equals` & `hashCode`, заточив их только на поле s и просто перегнать в `Set<Load>` ?

Comment: Теоретически можно для каких-то учебных задач, но такой подход не рекомендуется для серьезных задач, так как возникает нежелательная неопределенность.  К примеру, `Set.of(new Load(1, "1"), new Load(2, "2"), new Load(3, "3"), new Load(4, "3"))` с переопределенным хэшем уже вылетит с исключением `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate element: Load: i=4; s=3`.  Если добавлять в сет через список, то опять-таки запишется только первое значение.